# Which ions determine ionic conductivity of a salt solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, ions

Let's take $\ce{ZnSO4}$ salt solution in water for example. So the ions inside my solution will be $\ce{H+}$, $\ce{OH-}$, $\ce{Zn^2+}$ and $\ce{SO4^2-}$.

My questions are:

1. Is the ionic conductivity measured for the solution gives an idea of mobility of zinc ions and sulfate, or is it a result of all four ions combined?
2. When we change the salt concentration of zinc sulfate, do we change the ionic conductivity of zinc and sulfate ions only, or all four ions?

Also, any undergrad university level source to understand this concept will be helpful.

Comment: Why is this being flagged-to-close as homework?!?

Answer (score -1):

Di water H2O has very poor conductivity. Because H+ and OH- only driven by the ionic product.

2 H2O <=> H3O+ +OH-

If any other ions will be add the condictivity rises . So that can be for example by acids (H+), alcaline  solutions (OH-) and salts (Cations and anions). The conductivity of the salts  >>>>>> as of the water. So mainly in your case zinc and sulphate drive it. But to calculate correctly all 4 ions participate.